# Logarithmic equation problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I’m working through an old copy of K.A.Stroud, Engineering Mathematics (5th ed) and one of the exercises has the following logarithm problem where the aim is to re-write without logs:

$\ln{I} = \ln{(2V)} - \{\ln{(KR + r)} - \ln{K} + KL\}$

The provided answer is:

$I = \frac{2Ve^{KL}}{K(KR+r)}$

I can’t quite get there as I end up with the e term in the denominator. Would be great to see a worked solution if anyone has the time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi there. Please give more details such as showing the steps you have tried.

Comment: Are you familiar with $\ln$ properties ? $\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$ for example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're right about the $e$ term in the denominator.

Simplifying,

$$\ln{I}=\ln{2V}-\{\ln(KR+r)-\ln{K}+KL\}$$
$$\implies \ln{I}=\ln{2V}-\ln(KR+r)+\ln{K}-KL$$
$$\implies \ln{I}=\ln{2V}-\ln(KR+r)+\ln{K}-\ln{e^{KL}}$$
$$\implies \ln{I}=\ln\left({2V}{\frac{1}{KR+r}}{K}{\frac{1}{e^{KL}}}\right)$$
$$\implies \ln{I}=\ln\left(\frac{2VK}{(KR+r)e^{KL}}\right)$$
$$\implies I=\frac{2VK}{(KR+r)e^{KL}}$$

Comment: Perfect, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have made a typo; I hope the original expression was $$\ln I = \ln(2V) - (\ln(KR+r)+\ln(K)-KL)$$

Then we get
$$\begin{aligned}I &= e^{\ln(2V)-(\ln(KR+r)+\ln(K)-KL)}\\ &=e^{\ln(2V)}e^{-(\ln(KR+r)+\ln(K)-KL)}\\&=\dfrac{e^{\ln(2V)}}{e^{(\ln(KR+r)+\ln(K)-KL)}}\\&=\dfrac{2V}{e^{(\ln(KR+r)+\ln(K)-KL)}}\\&=\dfrac{2V}{e^{(\ln(KR+r)}e^{\ln(K)}e^{-KL}}\\&=\dfrac{2V}{(KR+r)(K)\dfrac{1}{e^{KL}}}\\&=\dfrac{2Ve^{KL}}{K(KR+r)} \end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thanks. There’s no typo. Just double-checked the book and it’s as I wrote it. Looks like one for the errata. I had a look online for an errata page for this edition, but it’s >20yrs old and couldn’t find anything.  Appreciate you going thru it and glad I was along the right lines!